# Regular Expression for VAT Number

Tags: regex

I need an Javascript Regular Expression to match exactly as below

```
BE0xxxyyyzzz and BE0xxx.yyy.zzz
```

X - is only numeric

Example:-
BE0876.513.972 and BE876513972

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the `.` optional.  Everything else seems straight-forward:

```
/^BE0[0-9]{3}[.]?[0-9]{3}[.]?[0-9]{3}$/
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use one of these expressions:

```
(BE0\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d|BE0\d\d\d\.\d\d\d\.\d\d\d)
```

or

```
(BE0(\d){9}|BE0(\d){3}\.(\d){3}\.(\d){3})
```

If the BE0 can vary in format based upon the examples you provided, you could also:

```
(BE(\d)?(\d){9}|BE(\d)?(\d){3}\.(\d){3}\.(\d){3})
```